# Alteração densidade da imagem (DPI)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou trabalhando com um projeto que faço captura de imagem e preciso transmitir essa imagem com 200dpi, gostaria de saber como faço para alterar a densidade da imagem para 200 dpi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... pergunta classicas... Vou tentar explicar, porque isso não e "diretamente" possivel. O DPI significa DOT PER INCH. Isso e a densidade não da imagem, mas da "macina" que vai permitir visualizar a imagem.
Por exemplo você tem uma imagem de 3000x3000. 
Numa impessora com 600 DPI-> 3000/600 = 5 inchs. Um inch : 2,54cm entaão a imagem vai fazer, no papel 5x2,54 = 12,7 cm.
A tela de seu computador tem um "DPI" de 72 até 108 DPI. No caso de 96 DPI (basico um 23" full hd), vamos ter uma imagem de:
3000/96 = 31 inch entao 31x2,54 = 78cm.

Isso significa que você não pode alterar realmente os DPI da imagem, porque a imagem não tem DPI. Ela tem pixels, nada mas.

Mas de verdade, deixa a imagem nesta forma, envia e espera. Em 99,99% dos casos, a pessão que "precisa de XX DPI" sabe nada disso.